# WSO2 Identity Server tenant requests no longer working

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I recently upgraded to version 6.1.0. I was previously using 5.11.0. When using the API to manage the tenants I was able to use the endpoint

```
https://localhost:9443/t/carbon.super/api/server/v1/tenants
```

while using Basic authentication. This worked perfectly fine until I upgraded and now my requests no longer work against this endpoint, I am receiving this message.

```
{
    "traceId": "911a1dac-a190-4afb-8919-65c8ed13e1ce",
    "code": 401,
    "description": "Authorization failure. Authorization information was invalid or missing from your request.",
    "message": "Unauthorized"
}
```

I also tested out version 6.0.0 and I am having the same problem. The documentation says Basic authentication should still work and there looks to be no differences in the endpoints documentation, even the curl it generates looks the same.

Comment: Error says it's a authorization failure. Authenticated user doesn't have the required scopes to access this endpoint.

Comment: @Asha I'm using the super tenant user, which is an admin, so I should have all the required permissions. Did anything change that isn't listed in the docs about how to authorize? Is Basic authentication in the header still allowed with username and password?

Answer (score 0):

From IS 6.0.0 onwards, tenanted paths are restricted for tenant management APIs with the improvement[1]. The correct endpoint URL is,

```
https://localhost:9443/api/server/v1/tenants
```

Documentations for 6.0.0 and 6.1.0 versions should be updated with the above endpoint URL and will be tracked with this doc issue[2].

[1] - https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/10653

[2] - https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/19322